# Unable to use the controller templates in VS2019

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have a "ASP.NET Core Web App" project. I right click my "Controllers" folder, choose "Add" then "Controller..." (I can choose "New Scaffolded Item" too, end result will be the same).

That brings me to this page:
[image: Add New Scaffolded Item]

I choose "MVC Controller with read/write actions", click "Add", and then I get this:

[image: Add New Item]

Which is the same I'd get by right clicking my folder and choose "Add" then "New Item...".

I can then choose whatever and click "Add", I won't get anything like an MVC controller.

I don't understand the logic, but it also isn't what is described in various MS tutorials or youtube videos... How do I get to add a new scaffolded item?

Comment: You can try to repair or reinstall your Visual Studio, and check if it can help fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks :) Already did that, also upgraded since a newer version got released. No difference.